# Number finder regex issue

Tags: javascript, regex

There is an input form 7(7**)************, and user enters any digit in any place instead of star(There are 10 stars after 7). For example  7(7**)7**188*8,7(7*0)12****198* or 7(700)123*123*,etc.And then the system should return numbers matching to the input. So,if the input is 7(7**)7**188*8, it should return all the phone numbers which has appropriate numbers in the right place, i.e. 770171318868,776771218858,etc should be returned. I've looked around regex, patterns and match. it seems to be a big topic, could you please direct me to the more exact place?

Comment: What are the parenthesis for?

Comment: That's how input text is.

Comment: Can I ignore the `()`?

Comment: yes, lets suppose its preprocessed and you can ignore it.

Comment: ^77\d{2}7\d{2}188\d{1}8$

Comment: @Jord I think my question wasn't clear. I've edited have a look

Comment: They way I understood is: you have several forms:
Some have 7(7**)**** some (7**)7**188*8 and some 7(7*0)12****198* you have all these values predefined! and user can only enter values inplace of * ????

Comment: @Jord thnx, I accepted the answer already. only 7(7**)******** is predefined, user can enter digits instead of stars, and then it is sent as input to my function which supposed to find matching numbers from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
var str = "7(7**)7**188*8";
var res1 = str.replace(/[\(\)]/g,'').replace(/\*/g, '\\d');
var re = new RegExp(res1);
console.log(re.test("770171318868"));
console.log(re.test("776771218858"));
```

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear with my question. I've edited it have a look. I didn't mean any specific input

Comment: i accidentally upvoted you instead of accepting. so i downvoted,after accepting. did i do smth wrong?

Comment: lol, downvote me again, if you really want to downvote. then only it will work